# jquery removing html element from variable

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have html saved in a variable

```
var  itinerary =  $('.events_today').html() ;
```

I have lots of html and one button I want to remove. It has the id "myButton". How can I remove it from the html saved in my variable

Comment: That's a tough one. I'd like to see the best way to do this. Any chance you can't remove it after you append it?

Comment: @Roscoeh, have you tried some of the proposed solutions?

Answer (score 10):

I suggest this approach

```
var itinerary = $('.events_today')
                .clone(true)       /* get a clone of the element and from it */
                .find('#myButton') /* retrieve the button, then */
                .remove()          /* remove it, */
                .end()             /* return to the previous selection and */
                .html() ;          /* get the html */
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
itinerary.filter(function() { return $(this).not("#myButton"); });
```

Comment: this helped me for removing element from ajax response, eg: $(response).not('#element_id');

Answer (score 0):

Just locate the element by it's id and remove:

```
$('#myButton').remove()
```

Then get your itinerary:

```
var itinerary =  $('.events_today').html() ;
```

// The above will remove the button from the DOM. To just get the html without having the button taken out of the DOM you can do:

```
var itinerary = $('.events_today').clone(true).find('#myButton').remove().end().html();
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to remove it from the DOM, just the variable

Answer (score 0):

Find the element in the collection and remvoe it.

`$('.events_today').find('#myButton').remove();`

**Edit:** After realizing I might've misunderstood the OP, this might work (although not exactly very beautiful).

```
var html = $('.events_today').html();
// Parse the html, but don't add it to the DOM
var jqHtml = $(html);
// Find and remove the element with the specified id.
jqHtml.find('#myButton').remove();
// Get the new html without the myButton element.
var result = jqHtml.html();
```

Update: Based on @Fabrizio Calderan's answer you can do what I did above much more nicely with jQuery methods.

Comment: See my comment on qci's answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var html = $('#myHtml').clone(true).find('#elementThatYouWantToRemove').remove().end().html();
```

Comment: Why are you cloning the parent element?