# Element find and remove from string/variable using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am storing some HTML in a variable. Now I want to remove some div tags from this variable: `editor_data`:

```
function validate_step_3()
{
    var editor_data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData(); 
    var i = $(editor_data);
    alert(i);
}
```

The alert shows:

> [object Object]

I want to remove this div

```
editor_data.find('#fetch_InCkeditor').remove();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use jquery in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442322/how-to-use-jquery-in-a-string)

Comment: I think it is not resolveable question.

Comment: Can you tell us how you store and what you store

Comment: It depends on what you do with the variable afterwards. The duplicate shows how to remove the element, but remember that the original string will not change automatically; you have to convert the DOM elements back to HTML.

Comment: Hi Chamika, I am storing html throw CKEditor, get input and store it in a variable `editor_data `, then I want to remove a div tag in this variable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$(editor_data).find('#fetch_InCkeditor').remove();` will do. :)

Comment: At my end i'm able to remove. And $('#fetch_InCkeditor').remove(); will work as well.

Comment: I think in http://stackoverflow.com/a/14756843/1145706 they found the answer. The important thing is to clone the variable before removing things.

Answer (score 0):

**id** on a page is supposed to be **unique**.

So in this case just this should be sufficient `$('#fetch_InCkeditor').remove();`

Comment: but html data is save in variable, my question is how I find this div in variable and then remove it.thanks